# Jenkins: Build job with dependency to other artifact/project

Tags: java, jenkins, gradle, build

I'm trying to configure my jenkins jobs but I have some problems regarding the setup.

**My Goal:**

- One build job for the core project
- One build job for a project which has dependencies to the core project

**Current Setup:**

```
- core 
-- src/
-- build.gradle
-- settings.gradle
- project
-- src/
-- build.gradle
-- settings.gradle
```

"core" and "project" are in separate git repositories.

The settings.gradle of the "project" contains the following code:

```
include ':drivers', ':capabilities', ':features', ':extensions', ':pageobjects', ':reports'
project(':drivers').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../core/drivers')
project(':capabilities').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../core/capabilities')
project(':features').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../core/features')
project(':extensions').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../core/extensions')
project(':pageobjects').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../core/pageobjects')
project(':reports').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../core/reports')
```

So, the "project" needs the modules of the core. On my local machine (using eclipse, one workspace) it works like a charm, but I don't know how to setup the jenkins jobs. Maybe the path to settingsDir is not suitable for Jenkins? It's also possible to include both repositories in one job, but it would be better if there are two build jobs.

How do I configure this properly?

Answer (score 0):

In your case as you want to use different Jobs for Core and Project, the gradle settings projectDir doesn't meet the path structure with respective to Jenkins workspaces if you use as is which comes by Jenkins default workspace management.

Use [Custom Workspace](http://ingorichter.blogspot.in/2012/02/jenkins-change-workspaces-and-build.html), which helps this to point to the folder where you have setup a folder similar to the Dev folder structure.

Ex:
Create root folder to hold the Core and Projects and assuming that you are running Jenkins (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/code)

Code

-core

--src/

--build.gradle

--settings.gradle

-project

--src/

--build.gradle

--settings.gradle

Use the custom workspace for core job as **/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/code/core**

and for the project job use the custom workspace as **/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/code/project**

Comment: Thank you for your help. I used the custom workspace and it works like a charm.